# Voltage generated by piezoelectric effect

Tags: voltage, piezoelectric-effect

When you apply a voltage to a insulator if the insulator is shaped appropriately its shape is changed.

When the piece of insulator returns to its initial state a voltage is generated by which is its polarity compared to the original voltage?

Comment: If C changes with shape, the. Q=CV is preserved if no leakage, but Current is generated from acceleration of motion (piezo effect). This is true for all ceramic except NPO

Comment: What about the direction of the current compared to the current which had changed the shape of the insulator.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage is related to the amount of mechanical strain/stress in the material and is a dynamic equation (has states changes over time):
[image]
Source: https://onscale.com/piezoelectricity/the-behavior-laws-of-piezoelectricity/

In short: to calculate the voltage generated, one needs to know

1. the material and it's parameters
2. the stress in the material (and how that is changing over time) which is derived from force and material properties.

> When the piece of insulator returns to its initial state a voltage is
> generated by which is its polarity compared to the original
> voltage(step 1)?

Without getting too deep into the equations, the stress in the material starts to generate an electric field (the electrons have to be there in the first place). This then generates a voltage (and reduces the strain). If the strain is held steady then the voltage will be steady ( they build strain gauges with piezo electric materials). As the material relaxes, the voltage of the material falls (zero strain = zero voltage). So if the material is relaxing the voltage doesn't reverse, it falls toward zero. If you wanted to get a negative voltage, then you'd need to pull the piezo electric module instead of push it.

Comment: I'll add that some electronic cigarette lighters work by having a spring-loaded weight slam into a piezo crystal at high velocity. The relatively fast shockwave generates a high voltage, which emanates as a spark, igniting the fuel.

Comment: I've also seen a few equations where they have a constant for that specific module, so higher shock = higher voltage. Piezo transformers are really cool